# Distributing Python programs with Apache while avoiding CGIWrap

Tags: apache-http-server, python, http, web, cgi

I want to publish Python programs on the web, not execute them. When I put one in my web directory, CGIWrap jumps up and says:

**"CGIWrap Error: Execution of this script not permitted"**

What configuration can I give to Apache or CGIWrap so that it serves the content of .py files instead of getting into the above?

Comment: If they have a .py extension, you should probably change that (use .txt or .html, if anything). Likewise, I would consider removing any shebang lines and simply specify they need to be added back. If you're distributing them, wrapping them in a compressed format should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145517/executing-a-python-script-in-apache2) on how TO execute a python script, I grabbed:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

This, and a quick trip over to [the apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#removehandler) (to learn the reverse of AddHandler), leads me to suggest:

```
Options -ExecCGI
RemoveHandler .py
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: This seems like the right approach, but apparently there is an AllowOverride setting upstream that stops me from testing it (i.e., the .htaccess file is not read). I will ask the sysadmin if doing so is the only way forward.

Comment: Ah! That's annoying. Any change you can just rename the files to ".py.txt"?

Comment: I'm not going to do that, but you put me on the right track. Thanks!